# How to detailview pk in post method in DetailView? (Django)

Tags: python, django

In my detailView I have 2 methods `get_context_data` and `post`. In `get_context_data` I can get the detailView pk with `self.object.pk` but how can I get it in the `post` method?

[ updated ]

here is the view

```
class Class_detailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    login_url = '/'
    model = Class
    template_name = "attendance/content/teacher/class_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['attendance_form'] = AttendanceForm(current_class_pk=self.object.pk) # pass data to form via kwargs 
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == "POST":
            attendance_form = AttendanceForm(request.POST)
            if attendance_form.is_valid():
                attendance_form.instance.teacher = self.request.user
                attendance_form.save()
                return redirect('class-detail', pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

form

```
class AttendanceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Attendance
        fields = ['student',]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        current_class_pk = kwargs.pop('current_class_pk')
        super(AttendanceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        current_student = Class.objects.get(id=current_class_pk)
        self.fields['student'].queryset = current_student.student
```

I want to get the pk and pass it to the form when the post request is called.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try this:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == "POST":
        attendance_form = AttendanceForm(request.POST, current_class_pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        if attendance_form.is_valid():
            attendance_form.instance.teacher = self.request.user
            attendance_form.save()
            return redirect('class-detail', pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```